# How to handle StreamReader?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use StreamReader to read my csv file.
The problem is : i need to read this file twice, and in second time then i use StreamReader 
StreamReader.EndOfStream is true and reading not executed.

```
using (var csvReader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream))
            {
                string inputLine = "";
                var values = new List<string>();

                while ((inputLine = csvReader.ReadLine()) != null)...
```

Can enybody help

Answer (score 2):

Try `file.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` before you open the second `StreamReader` to reset the `Stream` to the starting point.

Comment: Hi file.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); not work in this case... I was try it :(

Comment: @user, that stream should be ressetable - you should post all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

A much better approach(if possible) would be to store the file contents in memory, and re-use it from there.